# I can't find the right data-bind for my knockout.js code

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

**This is my html**

```
<input id="places-search" data-bind="textInput: str, event: {input: filter}" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Loft">
          <div id="list-result">
            <ul class="navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: res">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" data-bind="attr: {title: elem}" onclick="popLWInfo(id)"></button>
```

**And my javascript**

```
<script>
var filterer = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.str = ko.observable("");
  var location = function(data){
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.marker = ko.observable(data.marker);
  };
  self.res = ko.observableArray();
  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    self.res.push(new location({id: i , marker: markers[i]}));
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried using different words for the "foreach: res"
and i tried adding 'data-bind="with: filterer"' 
**but the array won't display**
i still don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: What is the issue? Your `foreach` is not working?

Comment: It is not very clear what the exact issue is. Also it would be so much easier if you had somewhat of a working example/snippet.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, it's hard to identify exactly what the issue is. If you could paste the entire example or create a JSFiddle then that would be great.

Although it might have been omitted from your original post, I don't see any call to `ko.applyBindings` which would handle taking your view model and applying it to the HTML.

```
// Insert this code after your function definition
(function(){
    var model = new filterer();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
})();
```